# Modelling Magento in Talend MDM

Tags: magento-1.9, pim, talend-mdm

Does anyone have any case studies of using Talend MDM to store Magento product data? I'd like to use the Talend MDM as a PIM. Where would I start as there is very little information out there on how to use the PIM features in Talend MDM.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

As an experienced user of Talend products my advice is to go directly to the source.  Start with reading these short articles that mention PIM [here](http://www.talend.com/blog/2014/08/27/key-capabilities-of-mdm-for-product-information-management-mdm-summer-series-part-10) and [here](http://www.talend.com/blog/2014/08/27/key-capabilities-of-mdm-for-product-information-management-mdm-summer-series-part-10) and contacting the [author](http://www.talend.com/blogger/jean-michel-franco) for a case study or further information.